# SPF "include:" does MX stay as included domain's MX, or get translated to the includer's MX?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spam, spf, txt-record

SPF records allow you to include another's domains SPF record within your own. For example, `example.com` can have `include:_spf.google.com` in its SPF record to include all of the SPF rules for `_spf.google.com`.

What happens to the `mx` and plain `a` (with no `:hostname`) parts of the included rules for `example.com`?

Would `mx` be parsed as the MX records for `_spf.google.com` or `example.com`?

(and yes I'm aware that there are no MX records for `_spf.google.com`, but I'm just trying to use an obvious `include:` example, but for a situation where there was one)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, just for clarity on `include`, [s5.2 of RFC 4408 says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-5.2):

> Only the evaluated result of the referenced SPF record is used, rather
> than acting as if the referenced SPF record was literally included in
> the first.

As to whether the `MX` RR in an `include`d record refers to your `MX`, or the `MX` of the `include`d domain, I cheerfully concede that [OpenSPF's protocol page](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include) is incredibly unhelpful on the subject, **because their example uses the same domain for both source and included record**.  But the RFC is (very slightly) clearer, when it writes (again in s5.2):

> The "include" mechanism triggers a recursive evaluation of check_host().  **The domain-spec is expanded as per Section 8.  Then
> check_host() is evaluated with the resulting string as the <domain>**.
> The <ip> and <sender> arguments remain the same as in the current
> evaluation of check_host().

I have highlighted the bit that I interpret as meaning that `mx` and similar records are evaluated in the context of the `include`d domain.  But since nothing is as good as Real Data, I defined the following subdomains in one of my family's domains (`waide.me.uk`, and thanks for the temporary loan!):

```
foo     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:bar.waide.me.uk -all"
foo     IN      A       10.5.5.5

bar     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx -all"
bar     IN      MX      5       baz.bar
baz.bar IN      A       78.46.204.154
```

When I use the [Beveridge tester](http://tools.bevhost.com/spf/) (that openspf.org recommends), it says that mail from `fred@foo.waide.me.uk` arriving from `78.46.204.154` is an SPF pass.  Note that no reference is made to that address *anywhere* in `foo.waide.me.uk`.  There *is* an `MX` reference in `bar.waide.me.uk`'s `included` record, but **`foo.waide.me.uk` has no MX**.  If the `MX` in the `include`d record were not evaluated in the context of the `include`d domain (`bar.waide.me.uk`) it could not resolve at all.

And just for completeness, when I remove the `include` from `foo.waide.me.uk`'s SPF record, then as we would now expect, Beveridge reports a fail.

Comment: Based on my experience with gmail, they interpret included MX differently (as the MX of the including domain). Might be a bug, but to be safe it might be prudent to not rely on this feature at all.